# Sending Auto-filled Email from Content Type Profiles

Tags: forms, nodes, emails

I have 'resource' content types. There are hundreds. I want each profile to contain an individualized link to a 'feedback form', or some mechanism to report an error with the profile, by email...to our staff. These items are coming from the DB, obviously. So something like the following:

Resource Name
Type
Description
[LINK to submit problem about this profile]
more details here

When the user clicks the link (in my imagination) they would either be able to send an email to someone on our staff with details auto-filled about the resource they are complaining about, OR, it takes them to a feedback form of some type with details auto-filled about the resource they are complaining about. Either way it auto-fills form fields and allows the sending of email.

Anyone know of a good module or technique for handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Webform for this kind of thing, as long as the values being passed to the form aren't too extensive.

On the Resource page template, create links to the webform, with field values in the the URL.

Webform 4 can then use tokens to place those values from the URL into fields.

You can then use [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) to send an email.

The same thing can be accomplished with [Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform), [Entity Reference,](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate), and Rules.